# Understanding exact behaviour of UP button in android

Tags: android

how does up button exactly behave in android, I mean does it check back stack or the manifest file only and if we need to specify the intent explicitly and use navigateUpTo to go to previous activity what is the need of declaring parent in the manifest file. For example I have a main activity A then I have another activity B who has parent as A defined in the manifest file. Then I have a third activity C whose parent is B defined in the manifest file. Now when I go from A to C directly and press UP button of C I can't understand why it goes back to A rather than going to B which is it's parent according to the manifest file. Please do reply. I have searched it for 2 days now.

Comment: Ux-wise, wouldn't it be terrible to have it jump "back" to an unvisited page?

Comment: Well I am not asking the question in Ux context, I am more interested in understanding the concept of the process.